# Play2 iteratee and enumerator streaming of large file fails

Tags: scala, streaming, playframework-2.0, enumerator, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play2 Framework proxy streaming content to client keeps connection open after streaming is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736320/play2-framework-proxy-streaming-content-to-client-keeps-connection-open-after-st)

I am streaming a 11mb file from a web service to the client. This is essentially a pass-through proxy. here's my code:

```
def getStreamEnumerator(streamUrl: String, mimeType: String) = {
    Akka.future {
        val dataContent = Enumerator.imperative[Array[Byte]]()

        WS.url(streamUrl).withHeaders("Accept"->mimeType).get { response =>
            Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], PushEnumerator[Array[Byte]]](dataContent)({
                (pipe, bytes) => {
                    println(bytes.length)
                    pipe.push(bytes)
                    pipe
                }
            })
        }.orTimeout("Oops", 20000L).map {eitherPromiseOrTimeout =>
            println(eitherPromiseOrTimeout)
            dataContent.close()
        }
        dataContent
    }
}
```

and I call it:

```
        getStreamEnumerator(imageUrl, "image/png").map { e =>
            Ok.stream(e).withHeaders(
                "Content-Type"->"image/png",
                "Connection"->"Close"
            )
        }
```

for slow services, this works great, I get the entire file. For fast services, I only get a small portion of the file (which varies in size, btw), with the rest of the image cut off. If the image is, say, 11mb, I may only get, 2mb before the .close() methods kills the stream.

I KNOW that the Iteratee gets all of the data (I see it when I print it out), but, it seems like the .close() call on the Enumerator runs too soon, and cuts off the enumerator before the interatee is able to fill it up.

I have a few questions:

1. is this the right way to go about doing a proxy? I first did this with traditional Java IO streams, which worked OK, but wasn't idiomatic or non-blocking
2. IF this is a reasonable way to go about solving this problem, where should the Enumerator.close() method go? .onRedeem has the same issue as .orTimeout

Thank you!